# Angular/Breeze: Hanging on save - how to troubleshoot?

Tags: angularjs, breeze

Since a couple of days, I'm struggling with this problem. When I try to save changes (very small change, only one property changed) it got stuck. In Chrome, when I hit break, I got following call stack:

```
(anonymous function) (breeze.debug.js:8113)
__toJSONSafe (breeze.debug.js:175)
__toJSONSafe (breeze.debug.js:187)
__toJSONSafe (breeze.debug.js:168)
__toJSONSafe (breeze.debug.js:187)
__toJSONSafe (breeze.debug.js:187)
__toJSONSafe (breeze.debug.js:187) (anonymous function) (breeze.debug.js:175)
__toJSONSafe (breeze.debug.js:175)
__toJSONSafe (breeze.debug.js:187)
__toJSONSafe (breeze.debug.js:187)
__toJSONSafe (breeze.debug.js:187) (anonymous function) (breeze.debug.js:175)
__toJSONSafe (breeze.debug.js:175)
__toJSONSafe (breeze.debug.js:187) (anonymous function) (breeze.debug.js:175)
__toJSONSafe (breeze.debug.js:175)
__toJSONSafe (breeze.debug.js:187)
__toJSONSafe (breeze.debug.js:187)
__toJSONSafe (breeze.debug.js:187)
__toJSONSafe (breeze.debug.js:187)
__toJSONSafe (breeze.debug.js:187)
__toJSONSafe (breeze.debug.js:187) (anonymous function) (breeze.debug.js:175)
__toJSONSafe (breeze.debug.js:175)
__toJSONSafe (breeze.debug.js:187)
__toJSONSafe (breeze.debug.js:187)
__toJSONSafe (breeze.debug.js:187) (anonymous function) (breeze.debug.js:175)
__toJSONSafe (breeze.debug.js:175)
__toJSONSafe (breeze.debug.js:187) (anonymous function) (breeze.debug.js:175)
__toJSONSafe (breeze.debug.js:175)
__toJSONSafe (breeze.debug.js:187)
__toJSONSafe (breeze.debug.js:187)
__toJSONSafe (breeze.debug.js:187)
__toJSONSafe (breeze.debug.js:187) (anonymous function) (breeze.debug.js:175)
__toJSONSafe (breeze.debug.js:175)
__toJSONSafe (breeze.debug.js:187)
__toJSONSafe (breeze.debug.js:187)
__toJSONSafe (breeze.debug.js:187) (anonymous function) (breeze.debug.js:175)
__toJSONSafe (breeze.debug.js:175)
__toJSONSafe (breeze.debug.js:187)
__toJSONSafe (breeze.debug.js:187) (anonymous function) (breeze.debug.js:175)
__toJSONSafe (breeze.debug.js:175)
__toJSONSafe (breeze.debug.js:187)
__toJSONSafe (breeze.debug.js:187) (anonymous function) (breeze.debug.js:175)
__toJSONSafe (breeze.debug.js:175)
__toJSONSafe (breeze.debug.js:187)
__toJSONSafe (breeze.debug.js:187)
__toJSONSafe (breeze.debug.js:187)
__toJSONSafe (breeze.debug.js:187)
__toJSONSafe (breeze.debug.js:187)
__toJSONSafe (breeze.debug.js:187) (anonymous function) (breeze.debug.js:13975) unwrapInstance (breeze.debug.js:13963) (anonymous function) (breeze.debug.js:15394) ctor._prepareSaveBundle (breeze.debug.js:15393) breeze.AbstractDataServiceAdapter.ctor.saveChanges (breeze.debug.js:14704) proto.saveChanges (breeze.debug.js:12793) SaveQueuing.innerSaveChanges (breeze.savequeuing.js:98) saveChangesWithQueuing (breeze.savequeuing.js:81)
_saveEntity (commonContext.js:220)
_save (commonContext.js:295) (anonymous function) (angular.js:10294) isolateScope.(anonymous function) (angular.js:6243) (anonymous function) (angular.js:10294) (anonymous function) (angular.js:18229) Scope.$eval (angular.js:12075) Scope.$apply (angular.js:12173) (anonymous function) (angular.js:18228) jQuery.event.dispatch (jquery-2.0.3.js:4676) elemData.handle (jquery-2.0.3.js:4360)
```

How do I troubleshoot this kind of problem? What could possibly be the problem?

This page has quite a lot of bindings. Did I hit the limit of Angular binding? What's the limit?

UPDATE:
When I keep hitting break button, I often see it stopped at line 8113 of breeze.debug.js, where it throws new error.

```
proto.addProperty = function (dataProperty) {
    assertParam(dataProperty, "dataProperty").isInstanceOf(DataProperty).check();
    if (this.metadataStore && ! dataProperty.isUnmapped) {
        throw new Error("The '" + this.name + "' ComplexType has already been added to a MetadataStore and therefore no additional properties may be added to it.");
    }
    if (dataProperty.parentType) {
        if (dataProperty.parentType !== this) {
            throw new Error("This dataProperty has already been added to " + property.parentType.name);
        } else {
            return this;
        }
    }
    this._addDataProperty(dataProperty);

    return this;
};
```

So, is there something wrong with my data structure?

Comment: I doubt it's the number of binding, please show some sample code, both on client and server.

Comment: Well, I have quite a lot of code. I'm still trying to isolate the problem.

Comment: Okay, I figured out the problem in my case. My entity Batch has a collection of samples, and I added a new property called selectedSample on client side to track the currently selected sample which seems to cause Breeze to hang. Once I removed this selectedSample from batch, it works fine.